# Visual studio 2003, IIS

Tags: asp.net

In my system visual studio 2003 is installed but I am not able to create new Web projects in my user login it says some visual studio components are not installed properly. In Admin role it is posible.In user login if we type "http://localhost" it is showing "HTTP 500.100-Internet Server Error-ASP error”. If I wanted work in user role do we need IIS access? If required, how will I get access to it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a check list you can go through to debug the problem:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893665/en-us